# AvalonText custom highlight set in xaml wpf

Tags: wpf, xaml, syntaxhighlighter, avalonedit

I am trying to use the AvalonText wpf control with a custom xmhl highlighting file.  The control will appear as the row detail of a data grid so I can't set the highlighter at run time (or at least I don't know how) and would rather do it in XAML even if I can.  Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: You can't do everything in XAML. You can partially do something in XAML using dependency properties/behaviors but the rest of the logic will go to the class file and will have to do it in runtime.

Comment: That being the case, is there a way to do this initialization when the row detail is created?